# Get active RadioButton on GroupBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radiobuttonlist, groupbox

I've got 12 radiobuttons in GroupBox. I want to get id (or value) of this one, which is currently chosen (active). Is there any built-in C# function to do so and I need to write my own one?

Answer (score 0):

Get Controls into GroupBox and select checked RadioButton:

```
var radioButton = groupBox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(_ => _.IsChecked).
```